# Get all combinations from a list of lists (combination algorithm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartesian-product

Say I have this list of lists:

```
lst_of_lsts = [['1-1', '1-2', '1-3'], ['2-1', '2-2', '2-3'], ['3-1', '3-2', '3-3']]
```

How can I make an iteration that outputs me all possible combinations within `len(lst_of_lsts)`

Desired Output:

```
comb1 = ['1-1', '2-1', '3-1']
comb2 = ['1-2', '2-1', '3-1']
comb3 = ['1-3', '2-1', '3-1']
comb4 = ['1-1', '2-2', '3-1']
comb5 = ['1-2', '2-2', '3-1']
comb6 = ['1-3', '2-2', '3-1']
comb7 = ['1-1', '2-3', '3-1']
comb8 = ['1-2', '2-3', '3-1']
comb9 = ['1-3', '2-3', '3-1']
comb10 = ['1-1', '2-1', '3-2']
comb11 = ['1-1', '2-1', '3-3']
comb12 = ['1-1', '2-2', '3-2']
```

etc...
etc...
etc...

you get the idea..

Comment: What you want is called the "cartesian product" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product. "Combinations" is a little bit different of a concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you want isn't technically the list of *combinations* (where order doesn't matter), but rather the *product* of the given lists, li.e. all lists where the first element comes from the first list, the second elements comes from the second list, etc.

This (and many other useful related functions) are available in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library, particularly [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*lst_of_lsts))
[('1-1', '2-1', '3-1'), ('1-1', '2-1', '3-2'), ('1-1', '2-1', '3-3'), ('1-1', '2-2', '3-1'), ('1-1', '2-2', '3-2'), ('1-1', '2-2', '3-3'), ('1-1', '2-3', '3-1'), ('1-1', '2-3', '3-2'), ('1-1', '2-3', '3-3'), ('1-2', '2-1', '3-1'), ('1-2', '2-1', '3-2'), ('1-2', '2-1', '3-3'), ('1-2', '2-2', '3-1'), ('1-2', '2-2', '3-2'), ('1-2', '2-2', '3-3'), ('1-2', '2-3', '3-1'), ('1-2', '2-3', '3-2'), ('1-2', '2-3', '3-3'), ('1-3', '2-1', '3-1'), ('1-3', '2-1', '3-2'), ('1-3', '2-1', '3-3'), ('1-3', '2-2', '3-1'), ('1-3', '2-2', '3-2'), ('1-3', '2-2', '3-3'), ('1-3', '2-3', '3-1'), ('1-3', '2-3', '3-2'), ('1-3', '2-3', '3-3')]
```

Note the use of `*` since `product` expects the outer list as positional arguments, and the use of `list` (for nicer illustration) since `product`—as requested—returns an iterator.

Comment: All righty, now since this is a list of tuples. Can I for loop each tuple and assign the values to dictionary keys? for example: {var1: 1-1, var2: 2-1, var3: 3-1} and so on respectively?
Given the fact I have a dictionary with the len of keys == len of the list of lists. So, 3 vars for 3 values
BTW, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Yes, you can, e.g. `for (var1, var2, var3) in product(*lst_of_lsts): ...`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> res = list(itertools.product(*lst_of_lsts))
>>> res
[('1-1', '2-1', '3-1'), ('1-1', '2-1', '3-2'), ('1-1', '2-1', '3-3'), ('1-1', '2-2', '3-1'), ('1-1', '2-2', '3-2'), ('1-1', '2-2', '3-3'), ('1-1', '2-3', '3-1'), ('1-1', '2-3', '3-2'), ('1-1', '2-3', '3-3'), ('1-2', '2-1', '3-1'), ('1-2', '2-1', '3-2'), ('1-2', '2-1', '3-3'), ('1-2', '2-2', '3-1'), ('1-2', '2-2', '3-2'), ('1-2', '2-2', '3-3'), ('1-2', '2-3', '3-1'), ('1-2', '2-3', '3-2'), ('1-2', '2-3', '3-3'), ('1-3', '2-1', '3-1'), ('1-3', '2-1', '3-2'), ('1-3', '2-1', '3-3'), ('1-3', '2-2', '3-1'), ('1-3', '2-2', '3-2'), ('1-3', '2-2', '3-3'), ('1-3', '2-3', '3-1'), ('1-3', '2-3', '3-2'), ('1-3', '2-3', '3-3')]
```